# Cuando en la herencia se sobreescribe un metodo no es necesario crear getter y setter

Tags: java, sql, poo, clase-abstracta, sobrecarga

Soy nuevo en la comunidad, como primer lenguaje de programacion a Pesar de que algunos me lo han desaconsejado por su sintaxis rígida opte por java y después de 2 meses llegue a Poo, pero ayer haciendo un ejercicio me di cuenta de algo que ojalá ustedes me puedan aclarar, llegue al punto de una herencia de sobrescritura, yo siguiendo lo aprendido instancie dichas sobre escrituras en las clases hijas como un void como no tenía un return les agregue a las dos sobrescritura de las clases hijas un sistema.out.print y agregue además su get y set por atributos de cada clase incluida la súper clase, al terminar revise la solución y no tenía los métodos set y get, solo la super clase mi consulta es , la súper clase vendría a ser una especie de mezcla de setter y getter? Es decir tiene las mismas atribuciones de ellos que no es necesario crearlos?? Algo así entendi pero no me quedo claro gracias

Comment: Bienvenido. El texto está todo junto y es complicado de leer. Por favor separa un poco más las ideas, dale formato a tu pregunta y agrega el código con el que necesites ayuda.

Comment: Agrega el código para que sea más fácil entender el problema.